# All versions of one item in list

Tags: 2010, list, version-history

Is it possible to see all versions for one item in SP list a different way than through version history? We have one extensively used list with 100, 130, 150... with a lot of (multi-line and rich text) versions for one item and version history window sometimes lost side bars. Even if we turn off the dialogs, page lost their bars too and it is hard to navigate through them. We are searching for something like IncludeVersions=TRUE parameter, that works on old 2007 lists.

I'm almost sure, that Access 2007 can works with versions of SP lists, but we do not have any for months and I can't see this option in 2010 now.

I don't want to download them, backup or compare, I just want them to read :o)

Thank you for any clue.

Comment: I personally don't know any way to do this, but then again I didn't know of the IncludeVersions parameter either. It's fairly easy to create such a thing in a webpart, but that does require some custom coding of course.

Answer (score 2):

As @John mentioned this can be done using code. You need to get `SPListItemVersionCollection` associated with the list item. Loop through the versions and keep track of current and previous version. Also, you need to check whether field needs to be shown in version history using `SPield.ShowInVersionHistory`
I have created a custom solution which does version history export of single as well as multiple list items to MS Excel. You can find more about it here:
https://exportversionhistory.codeplex.com/

Comment: Clean & simple, thank you! Ill test it in our enviroment

Answer (score 1):

Other than using the UI to view/restore individual versions, the only other way I am aware of to view those versions is via code.  There is a good blog post about it over here: http://tipsinsharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/working-with-versions-in-sharepoint-list-programmatically/

The gist of it is that you get the SPListItem and then parse through its Versions property.

```
SPListItem listItem = // wherever you are getting this from
SPListItemVersionCollection listItemVersions = listItem.Versions;
if (listItemVersions != null && listItemVersions.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SPListItemVersion item in listItemVersions)
    {
        foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
        {
            // Do Something with the data
        }
    }
}
```