# Get List Item Version History using Client Side Object Model (C#)

Tags: 2013, development, client-object-model, version

I am using the Client Side Object Model `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` against SharePoint 2013, and am able to pull down data from custom lists.

What I am attempting to do now is to pull down the version history of each item. Is this possible from the client side?

It appears the code I've found out there is server side code?

- [All versions of one item in list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39216/all-versions-of-one-item-in-list)
- https://exportversionhistory.codeplex.com/

I've tried looking for the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`, but it appears to be a server only library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client Object Model doesn't provide versions property (which is available only on Server Side Object Model)

I believe your only hope is to rely on the web services

[SPservices to retrieve version history of items in SharePoint List 2007?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22958/spservices-to-retrieve-version-history-of-items-in-sharepoint-list-2007)

Comment: Thanks! It is surprising the CSOM doesn't allow this functionality. I am able to access this now through the web service.