# Unable to get the custom list item versions using (ListItem.Versions) inside my CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code inside my console application:-

```
CamlQuery camlQuery2 = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ProjectStage'/>" +
"<Value Type='String'>Closed</Value></Neq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem2 = oList.GetItems(camlQuery2);
context.Load(collListItem2);
foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem2){
foreach (var itemversion in oListItem.Versions)
```

but i am unable to get the ListItem Versions using `oListItem.Versions`!! where i got this error:-

> Error 1   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Versions' and no extension method 'Versions' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps for your reference.

1.Create a console application using visual studio.

2.Install the package using the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/) below.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM -Version 16.1.19515.12000
```

3.Refer to the code example below to get list items versions.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteURL = @"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
            string listTitle = "customlist";
            var login = "test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            var password = "xxx";

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);
            context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            var oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ProjectStage'/>" +
            "<Value Type='String'>Closed</Value></Neq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem= oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(collListItem);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem){
                Console.WriteLine("------------" + oListItem.Id);
                context.Load(oListItem.Versions);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItemVersion itemversion in oListItem.Versions)
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine(itemversion.VersionLabel+"|"+itemversion.FieldValues["Title"]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-september-2017/) article.

In short, you have to refer the newly released CSOM package **16.1.6906.1200** or higher.

You can find the latest CSOM package for SharePoint Online from the NuGet gallery with an id of ‘**Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM**‘.

Adding the code sample below.

```
// Get versions of specific document from library - item and file
 List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("DocumentLibraryTitle");
 ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
 ListItemVersionCollection versions = item.Versions;
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = item.File;
 FileVersionCollection fileVersions = file.Versions;
 ctx.Load(list); ctx.Load(item); ctx.Load(versions);
 ctx.Load(file); ctx.Load(fileVersions);
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();

 // Loop list item versions and access data of specific fields
 foreach (var version in versions)
 {
   string versionValue = string.Empty;
   if (version.FieldValues["FieldName"] != null)
   {
     versionValue = version.FieldValues["FieldName"].ToString();
   }

   // Do something with the value
   Console.WriteLine(version.VersionLabel + " - " + versionValue);
 }

 // Download all versions of specific file as individual docs
 int index = 0;
 foreach (var version in fileVersions)
 {
   var str = version.OpenBinaryStream();
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   // Notice that we assume in this case that it's docx file
   string filename = string.Format("d:\downloaded\doc-{0}.docx", index);
   using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
     str.Value.CopyTo(fs);
   }
   index++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSOM doesn't yet support this `Versions` property, you'll have to get through a REST call, see

[Get List Item Version History using Client Side Object Model (C#)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128527/get-list-item-version-history-using-client-side-object-model-c)

and

[SPservices to retrieve version history of items in SharePoint List 2007?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22958/spservices-to-retrieve-version-history-of-items-in-sharepoint-list-2007)